# react-stripe-elements CardElement throwing cross-origin error

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I am trying to create a Stripe payment form in my React JS application using react-stripe-elements. When I use the  component I get the following message.

> Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to
>   the actual error object in development.

If I use the individual element components (i.e. `CardExpiryElement`, `CardCVCElement`, `PostalCodeElement`) I am error free.

Any thoughts anyone? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using server-side rendering? If you are then try to wrap the component with <NoSSR> (from "react-no-ssr")

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CardElement than don't use other elements like CardExpiryElement or CardCVCElement etc, because CardElemets provides you everything

Answer (score 0):

In React a lot of things can throw this error.

This issue is open in React since 2017 [Cross-origin error passed to componentDidCatch incorrectly #10441](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10441)

That being said, in my case it was because of `JSON.parse()` function being called twice after the object was already unserialized.